# Fabric.js rectangle is not showing up

Tags: fabricjs

Why the rectangle is not showing up? I've found the examples at GitHub, official site etc. But they're not working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fCanvas;
    window.onload = function (){
        var oldCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', 
            { 
                width: oldCanvas.parentNode.clientWidth, 
                height: oldCanvas.parentNode.clientHeight 
            });
    }

    function CreateGraphicObject(id){
        //...

        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
        });
        fCanvas.add(rect);
        //fCanvas.renderAll(); - did not help
    }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call the function `CreateGraphicObject`? And what is the `id` passing in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I had created a fiddle. I hope it will help you.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mullainathan/hgnvaqej/

Answer (score 0):

You have created function but never called it, so the rectangle never gets created.

You just need to call the function, in your code I suppose the best place to call it after creating the `canvas`:

```
window.onload = function (){
    var oldCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', 
        { 
            width: oldCanvas.parentNode.clientWidth, 
            height: oldCanvas.parentNode.clientHeight 
        });

    CreateGraphicObject(); //I didn't pass any "id" because it makes no sense in the given code
}

function CreateGraphicObject(){

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill: 'red',
        width: 20,
        height: 20
    });
    fCanvas.add(rect);
    fCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: no, I've added onclick event to a div: <div class="objectItem" id='singleRoad' onclick="CreateGraphicObject('singleRoad')">. In the debugger I see the rectangle was added to fCanvas. But it's not showing.